# Create search list based on data from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array that should be used to create a list of search engines next to a search field.

I have this script which is working. However, it generates a select box of options - you enter a search phrase, select engine, and then get a result. However, since I have to change the markup to be using Bootstrap, I need to change the select box to an unordered list, like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li class="selected">Select</li>
   <li>Google</li>
   <li>Nyheder</li>
   <li>Studier</li>
 </ul>
```

If I try to change the select into `<ul id="global_search_filter" class="search_filter"></ul>` and `var option = jQuery(document.createElement("option"));` to `var option = jQuery(document.createElement("li"));`the scripts breaks.

How can I achieve the same functionality but change the markup from a select box to an unordered list with list options?

I have created a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1kcu4cjg/9/).

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction on how to solve this.

```js
el = document.getElementById("localdomain");
el.value = window.location.hostname;
if (!window.searchEngines) {
  window.searchEngines = [{
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "label": "Google",
    "querykey": "q",
    "id": "allWeb"
  }, {
    "url": "https://www.bing.com",
    "label": "Bing",
    "querykey": "q",
    "id": "bing",
    "param": {
      "doctype": "",
      "path": "",
      "cms_mode": ""
    }
  }, {
    "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "label": "Yahoo",
    "querykey": "q",
    "id": "yahoo",
    "param": {
      "gcse": "014167723083474301078:sxgnobjpld4"
    }
  }];
}

window.searchCallbacks = [];

jQuery(function() {

  var stripPath = function(path) {
    return path === "/" ? path : path.replace(/\/$/, "");
  };

  var isEngineCurrent = function(engine) {
    if (stripPath(engine.url) !== stripPath(document.location.origin + document.location.pathname)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (engine.param) {
      for (var key in engine.param) {
        if (getUrlParameter(key) !== engine.param[key]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };

  var forms = jQuery("form.search_form");
  forms.each(function() {
    var form = jQuery(this);
    var field = form.find("input.search_query");
    var filter = form.find(".search_filter");
    var resetForm = form.hasClass("search_reset");

    if (window.searchEngines) {
      for (var i = 0; i < window.searchEngines.length; i++) {
        var engine = window.searchEngines[i];
        var option = jQuery(document.createElement("option"));
        option.text(engine.label);
        option.val(i);
        if (!resetForm && isEngineCurrent(engine)) {
          option.attr("selected", "selected");
          field.val(getUrlParameter(engine.querykey));
        }
        filter.append(option);
      }
      form.submit(function(event) {
        var chosenEngine = window.searchEngines[filter.val()];
        form.attr("action", chosenEngine.url);
        form.attr("method", chosenEngine.method || "GET");
        field.attr("name", chosenEngine.querykey);
        if (chosenEngine.param) {
          for (var paramName in chosenEngine.param) {
            var input = jQuery(document.createElement("input"));
            input.attr("type", "hidden");
            input.attr("name", paramName);
            input.val(chosenEngine.param[paramName]);
            form.append(input);
          }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < window.searchCallbacks.length; i++) {
          var callback = window.searchCallbacks[i];
          if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback(chosenEngine, this);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="global_search_form" class="search_form search_reset" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" id="global_search_query" class="search_query" placeholder="Search where...?">
  <input id="localdomain" name="localdomain" type="hidden" value=" + window.location.hostname + ">

  <select id="global_search_filter" class="search_filter"></select>

  <button name="sa" id="submit-button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried for the unordered list. `li` element does not have an value attributte and you can't append `li`'s to `select`s. @Sammy, that's not how you create an element with jQuery. That is how you target an element, and in your case put it in a variable.

Comment: @Ionut I updated my question to include what I tried. I know that a li can't have a selected attribute, but what's the other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working **[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kcu4cjg/20/)**.

Here is a modified version of your code(*unfortunately you can't submit a form on Stack Overflow, but you can test the jsfiddle above*). Will update imediatelly with explications:

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so let's see what we have done here:

- First we replace the select with an `ul` container
- We append `li` elements to the `ul` parent
- We add the `data-selected` custom attribute on every `li` element with empty value except the first one which we add the selected value.
- We add the `data-value` attribute to the `li` element to replicate the value like when we have a select option value.
- On click of a dynamically added `li` element we bind the click event dinamically using **event delegation** to add the `selected` attribute value.
- On click of the `li` element we also add the selected value name to the Bootstrap button.

```js
el = document.getElementById("localdomain");
el.value = window.location.hostname;
if (!window.searchEngines) {
  window.searchEngines = [{
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "label": "Google",
    "querykey": "q",
    "id": "allWeb"
  }, {
    "url": "https://www.bing.com",
    "label": "Bing",
    "querykey": "q",
    "id": "bing",
    "param": {
      "doctype": "",
      "path": "",
      "cms_mode": ""
    }
  }, {
    "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "label": "Yahoo",
    "querykey": "q",
    "id": "yahoo",
    "param": {
      "gcse": "014167723083474301078:sxgnobjpld4"
    }
  }];
}

window.searchCallbacks = [];

jQuery(function() {

  var stripPath = function(path) {
    return path === "/" ? path : path.replace(/\/$/, "");
  };

  var isEngineCurrent = function(engine) {
    if (stripPath(engine.url) !== stripPath(document.location.origin + document.location.pathname)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (engine.param) {
      for (var key in engine.param) {
        if (getUrlParameter(key) !== engine.param[key]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('li[data-selected="selected"]').attr('data-selected', '');
    $(this).attr('data-selected', 'selected');
    $("#menu").text($(this).text());
    $("#menu").val($(this).text());
  })
  var forms = jQuery("form.search_form");
  forms.each(function() {
    var form = jQuery(this);
    var field = form.find("input.search_query");
    var filter = form.find(".dropdown-menu");
    var resetForm = form.hasClass("search_reset");

    if (window.searchEngines) {
      for (var i = 0; i < window.searchEngines.length; i++) {
        var engine = window.searchEngines[i];
        var option = jQuery(document.createElement("li"));
        option.text(engine.label);
        option.attr('data-value', i);
        if (i == 0) {
          option.attr('data-selected', 'selected');
        } else {
          option.attr('data-selected', '');
        }
        option.attr('role', 'presentation');
        if (!resetForm && isEngineCurrent(engine)) {
          option.attr("selected", "selected");
          field.val(getUrlParameter(engine.querykey));
        }
        filter.append(option);
      }
      form.submit(function(event) {
        var chosenEngine = window.searchEngines[$('li[data-selected="selected"]').data('value')];
        console.log(chosenEngine);
        form.attr("action", chosenEngine.url);
        form.attr("method", chosenEngine.method || "GET");
        field.attr("name", chosenEngine.querykey);
        if (chosenEngine.param) {
          for (var paramName in chosenEngine.param) {
            var input = jQuery(document.createElement("input"));
            input.attr("type", "hidden");
            input.attr("name", paramName);
            input.val(chosenEngine.param[paramName]);
            form.append(input);
          }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < window.searchCallbacks.length; i++) {
          var callback = window.searchCallbacks[i];
          if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback(chosenEngine, this);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li[data-selected="selected"] {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="global_search_form" class="search_form search_reset" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" id="global_search_query" class="search_query" placeholder="Search where...?">
  <input id="localdomain" name="localdomain" type="hidden" value=" + window.location.hostname +">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose option
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button name="sa" id="submit-button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Meek, awesome. It needs a bit of adjustment but it's a start.